# expected type: java.lang.Integer, actual value: java.lang.Integer

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee, jboss

What am I trying to do ?
While loading my project I get a weird exception:

> rezg.admin.server.objects.common.pojo.EmailLogDetails, setter method of property: id

I am to save the object (persist) to the DB, using postgres. Environment is Java 6 , Hibernate 3 in Jboss 4 Environment. The jar contains "EmailLogDetails" is in the Jboss lib folder.

> expected type: java.lang.Integer, actual value: java.lang.Integer IllegalArgumentException in class:
>   rezg.admin.server.objects.common.pojo.EmailLogDetails, setter method
>   of property: id
>
> org.hibernate.PropertyAccessException: IllegalArgumentException
>   occurred while calling setter of
>   rezg.admin.server.objects.common.pojo.EmailLogDetails.Id  at
>   org.hibernate.property.BasicPropertyAccessor$BasicSetter.set(BasicPropertyAccessor.java:104)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.tuple.AbstractEntityTuplizer.setIdentifier(AbstractEntityTuplizer.java:204)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.setIdentifier(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3261)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:157)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:114).....
>
> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: object is not an instance of declaring class   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)     at
>   org.hibernate.property.BasicPropertyAccessor$BasicSetter.set(BasicPropertyAccessor.java:42)
>     ... 74 more

EmailLogDetails:

```
public class EmailLogDetails  implements java.io.Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private java.lang.Integer id;
private String reservationNo;
private String mailSubject;
private String fromAddress;

public String getFromAddress() {
    return fromAddress;
}
public void setFromAddress(String fromAddress) {
    this.fromAddress = fromAddress;
}
public java.lang.Integer getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(java.lang.Integer id) {
    this.id = id;
}
public String getMailSubject() {
    return mailSubject;
}
public void setMailSubject(String mailSubject) {
    this.mailSubject = mailSubject;
}
public String getMailType() {
    return mailType;
}
}
```

XML

```
<?xml version="1.0"?> 
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC 
    "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
    "../server/default/conf/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-mapping auto-import="false" schema="@@portalname@@_admin">
<class   name="rezg.admin.server.objects.common.pojo.EmailLogDetails" table="emaillogdetails">

      <id name="Id" column="id" type="java.lang.Integer">
        <generator class="sequence">
          <param name="sequence">@@portalname@@_admin.seq_emaillogdetails</param>
        </generator>
    </id>

    <property name="reservationNo"  type="java.lang.String" >
        <column name="reservationno" length="20" not-null="false" sql-type="varchar" />
    </property>

    <property name="mailSubject"  type="java.lang.String" >
        <column name="mailsubject" length="500" not-null="false" sql-type="varchar" />
    </property>
```

Comment: what you are trying to do ????

Comment: Man you need to provide more details, or at least a piece of your source-code.

Comment: I have added the code copied from the pojo and mapping xml

Answer (score 0):

By the looks of it you are missing the default constructor. Hibernate looks for the default constructor to create instances before playing around with import and export of mapping information between DB and class.

Comment: I have another set of classes with same, Without constructor.. What i want tu know is why this "java.lang.Integer, actual value: java.lang.Integer" came as exception . because both types are same .

Comment: Add the default constructor and try please.